# Kerberos ticket cache with PHP

Tags: php, apache, single-sign-on, kerberos, webmail

I am trying to get a full Kerberized domain environment configured, and one of the obstacles is webmail. I have scoured the Internet for information about how to do single sign on with Kerberos through webmail, but without definitive results. So now I am going to try and do it on my own.

The point is, while it is easy to authenticate against one service (the webmail frontend in this case) using mod_auth_kerb for Apache, forwarding a ticket to the IMAP/SMTP servers is proving more tricky. From the documentation about Kerberos that I have read it seems to be possible to accomplish this - The client would send a forwardable ticket to the webmail application, and then that server would use delegation to authenticate (as the user) to IMAP/SMTP. However, finding any actual information on existing implementations seems to be fruitless.

In attempting to make my own implementation, one of the first problems that I will face will be getting the ticket for use against the IMAP/SMTP servers. I can think of doing this one of two ways - either a forwardable ticket is stored at the point of authentication to the webmail, or whenever the user tries to send an email/refresh their mailboxes authentication occurs again, but this time no data is stored since it all occurs in one request (and mod_auth_kerb supports saving credentials for the duration of the request).

In going down the storing of credentials route, there are security concerns, scalability concerns and implementation concerns. However, authentication only happens once (whatever benefit that would give).

The reauthentication on refresh/send would be much more secure, since the credentials are only stored for the duration of the request due to mod_auth_kerb, and there should be fewer scalability issues since there will not be many credential caches floating around the place when many people are logged on. However, authentication would happen much more frequently, perhaps causing problems due to higher network load, or the chance that something bad would happen on the client between authenticating and attempting to send an email.

I am leaning towards the second method, simply because the security issues seem quite drastic, however I would like some more opinions - perhaps there is a better way of doing it?

EDIT: Another challenge which I will face is getting GSSAPI working with the PHP IMAP extension. From the material I have read it seems possible to do this one of two ways - either using Cyrus IMAP or using the built in GSSAPI mechanism in PHP IMAP. There is next to no documentation on how to do either method though, so help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you found an IMAP library which supports the GSSAPI mechasims for SASL at all? If not, it work work anyway.

Comment: I think it should be possible to use Cyrus IMAP, which supports Kerberos/GSSAPI through SASL. However it is true that this is a stumbling block that I haven't thought about until now.

Comment: Make this work first otherwise you will suffer big time. I guess you can use Cyrus IMAP with curl. That should be the easiest way t test it.